# Validate Uk formatted date

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate a uk date using this code:

```
function ukdate(d) {

    var p = new Date(d.split('/')[2], d.split('/')[1] -1, d.split('/')[0]);

    if(p.toString() !== 'Invalid Date') {
         return p;
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GE3xU/1/

so if I try **ukdate('31/12/1981')** it correctly returns "The Dec 31 1981". However if i try **ukdate('12/31/1981')** it returns "Tue Jul 12 1983".

Why is this happening? I'm expecting the second test to return invalid date because 31 is not a valid month.

Comment: As an aside: rather than `.split`ing your array 3 times, just split in once and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is converting your date for you.

In simple examples, you can get the last day of a given month by asking for the 0th day of the following month. Similarly, the "32nd of August" would be corrected to the 1st of September.

Months work similarly. The 13th month of a given year is the 1st month of the next. The 0th month of a year is December of the previous.

`31 % 12 = 7`, hence July, and `floor(31/12) = 2` hence the year being shifted forward by two.

This is intended behaviour for JavaScript.

May I interest you in `<input type="date" />`? It uses whatever format is defined on the user's computer (ie. it is "locale-aware"), which is already excellent for user experience. On top of that, supporting browsers will render a calendar date picker, especially useful on phones too. Internally, the date is in "standard" YYYY-mm-dd format.

Comment: Ah ok, So how do I reliably test for a valid date in UK format?!

Comment: `if( month < 1 || month > 12) alert("ARGLDURR!")` - use variables to hold the date parts, instead of repeatedly splitting the string.

Comment: Right, thought that might be the answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The month value is divided by 12 and added to the year, then the remainder is used as the actual month value.

See [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.12)

> Let ym be y + floor(m /12).
>   Let mn be m modulo 12.